# PHP file_get_html on Pinterest - Some seriously weird behaviour

Tags: php

Trying to scrape a bit of basic account info from Pinterest pages (no I'm not scraping pins before I get accused of using this maliciously, it's simply a competitor research tool).

Some accounts work fine with file_get_html, others return completely blank objects and I can't figure out why. I've built the below test code with completely random pages of different sizes to try and do some testing... still no further forward.

It uses Simple HTML DOM and here is my test code trying to figure out why some aren't working.

```
$pinterestUrl1 = "https://uk.pinterest.com/sfashionality/";
$pinterestUrl2 = "https://uk.pinterest.com/serenebathrooms/";
$pinterestUrl3 = "https://uk.pinterest.com/jenstanbrook/";
$pinterestUrl4 = "https://uk.pinterest.com/homebaseuk/";
$pinterestUrl5 = "https://uk.pinterest.com/thedoifter/";
$pinterestUrl6 = "https://uk.pinterest.com/coolshitibuy/";


$html1 = file_get_html($pinterestUrl1);
$html2 = file_get_html($pinterestUrl2);
$html3 = file_get_html($pinterestUrl3);
$html4 = file_get_html($pinterestUrl4);
$html5 = file_get_html($pinterestUrl5);
$html6 = file_get_html($pinterestUrl6);


echo $pinterestUrl1 . " - "; if (is_object($html1)) { echo "Returns object okay<br/>"; } else { echo "Failed<br/>"; };
echo $pinterestUrl2 . " - "; if (is_object($html2)) { echo "Returns object okay<br/>"; } else { echo "Failed<br/>"; };
echo $pinterestUrl3 . " - "; if (is_object($html3)) { echo "Returns object okay<br/>"; } else { echo "Failed<br/>"; };
echo $pinterestUrl4 . " - "; if (is_object($html4)) { echo "Returns object okay<br/>"; } else { echo "Failed<br/>"; };
echo $pinterestUrl5 . " - "; if (is_object($html5)) { echo "Returns object okay<br/>"; } else { echo "Failed<br/>"; };
echo $pinterestUrl6 . " - "; if (is_object($html6)) { echo "Returns object okay<br/>"; } else { echo "Failed<br/>"; };
```

**Result:**

```
https://uk.pinterest.com/sfashionality/ - Returns object okay
https://uk.pinterest.com/serenebathrooms/ - Returns object okay
https://uk.pinterest.com/jenstanbrook - Failed
https://uk.pinterest.com/homebaseuk/ - Failed
https://uk.pinterest.com/thedoifter/ - Returns object okay
https://uk.pinterest.com/coolshitibuy/ - Returns object okay
```

I can't see any reasons why some of these return objects and others don't... and because it's blank I don't even know where to start debugging this kind of thing.

Any ideas at all on this one? Thanks

Comment: I would try using `$doc = new DOMdocument(); $doc->load($url);` instead of `file_get_html` as this is from a 3rd party right?

Comment: file_get_html is from the Simple HTML DOM library - It's a pretty popular library so I'd be surprised if it was directly the issue. Could you give me an example of your suggestion as all my attempts simply throw " Call to a member function load() on a non-object in" - Thanks, appreciate the help

Comment: `$url = 'https://uk.pinterest.com/sfashionality/';
$doc = new DOMdocument();
$doc->load($url);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple HTML DOM parser has constant MAX_FILE_SIZE with value 600000 and URLs that you are requesting have slightly more HTML.
You can define MAX_FILE_SIZE with some larger value before including lib, this will produce a PHP notice but HTML will be processed. Code I have tested this with:

```
<?php
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 6000000); //Will produce notice, but we need to define it

include_once './simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php';

$urls = array(
    'https://uk.pinterest.com/sfashionality/',
    'https://uk.pinterest.com/serenebathrooms/',
    'https://uk.pinterest.com/jenstanbrook/',
    'https://uk.pinterest.com/homebaseuk/',
    'https://uk.pinterest.com/thedoifter/',
    'https://uk.pinterest.com/coolshitibuy/',
);

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $html = str_get_html($content);
    echo $url . ' - ';
    if (is_object($html)) {
        echo 'Returns object okay<br/>';
    } else {
        echo 'Failed<br/>';
    };
}
```

Comment: Boom! I would have spent a year getting to this. Hats off to you sir, well done! Thanks so much

Comment: P.s - I didn't need any of the $context part, I simply added the define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 6000000); at the start of my existing code. Is there a particular reason I should be using stream_context_create?

Comment: No, I have used it because I don't have OpenSSL properly set up and got connection errors for HTTPS URLs. I shall remove this code from my answer.